# Чем отличается "полчаса назад" от "полчаса тому назад"?

Tags: стилистика

Сравним два предложения:

Рынок стремительно пустел, и там, где **полчаса назад** кипела торговля и яблоку негде было упасть, оставались теперь лишь мусорные горы.

Мать стояла у той самой зеленой скамейки, где **полчаса тому назад** он разговаривал с бородатым раненым. [А. И. Пантелеев. Ленька Пантелеев (1938-1952)]

Может быть, местоимение в этом сочетание является "лишним" словом?

Кстати, частотность употребления в Нацкорпусе 362:91.

Answer (score 2):

"**Полчаса назад**" - время отсчитывается *от текущего момента* повествования (в первом примере это момент наблюдения за местом); "**полчаса *тому* назад**" - *относительно времени названного действия* (именно на него ссылаются местоимением **тому**), и в примере это время "стояния" матери на указанном автором месте. Обязательно ли "*тому*" во втором примере - вопрос отдельный (можно обойтись, а можно и обосновать). Если бы повествование велось в настоящем времени ("стоит мать там-то"), "тому" было бы лишним: это выражение употребимо только относительно момента из прошлого, как ссылка на нечто *ещё* более давнее.

Comment: Спасибо.  Но Вам не кажется, что можно обойтись без этой ссылки, так как ситуация с точки зрения времени и так понятна, а именно: полчаса разделяют два момента времени  Мне это местоимение кажется или архаическим,  или формальным.

Comment: В том тексте я бы обошёлся без "тому" (простое "за полчаса до этого" лучше сочетается с часами), но есть случаи (они более редки, что и видно из статистики), когда такой оборот необходим или полезен. _Было это в год юбилея основания Москвы - 800 лет тому назад Юрий Долгорукий..._

Comment: Да, здесь, пожалуй, местоимение ТОМУ на месте, но всё-таки  чаще  его употребление кажется лишним. А в наше динамичное время лишние слова заметно  "тормозят" текст.